# Nginx server goes down constantly when redeploying React application?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, jenkins

I am deploying my code onto a nginx server from Jenkins I have being following this process for a few months. There is a build script on my server box that a job configured in Jenkins picks up to know when pull down my latest changes and re build. In my nginx configuration looks like below. So you see currently getting the build folder in my root. And my build script just cp `/var/www/example` , `npm run build`, and `nginx restart` . Like I know the issue but Im getting confused on the proper steps to take because nginx shouldn't be getting my build folder while this script is running which is the reason im seeing `500 internal server` errors whenever i run the Jenkins job.

```
 
  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  #return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  #ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  #ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  #include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  #ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


  root /var/www/example/build/;
  index index.html;

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    access_log off;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
```

Comment: Why are you restarting nginx?

Comment: I changed it to reload, but the idea was to get the newest build again.

Comment: You only need to reload nginx if you change the configuration files. You don't need to reload it for changing your files.

Comment: This is my build script `#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/sleepless-gamer-ui
git pull origin main
echo "Initializing Environment..."
cp /work/.env /var/www/sleepless-gamer-ui
#sudo n latest
yarn install
npm run build`

Comment: I removed the nginx reload command. But i run into an issue when i kick off my Jenkins job. My server still goes does and shows a `403` or `500`